getting imapflow and mailparser to keep getting new message at a specific interval
been at this for 2 days now...
I get them to work and all fine but I need to keep getting new emails not just once or when I call the function.
Here is my code for this
const main = async () => {
  // Wait until client connects and authorizes
  await client.connect();

  // Select and lock a mailbox. Throws if mailbox does not exist
  let lock = await client.getMailboxLock("INBOX");
  // let mailbox = await client.mailboxOpen("INBOX");
  try {
    for await (let message of client.fetch(
      { seen: false },
      {
        envelope: true,
        internalDate: true,
        bodyStructure: true,
        flags: true,
        source: true,
      }
    )) {
      let parsed = await simpleParser(message.source);
      // const iconv = new Iconv("utf-8");
      app.get("/test", async (req, res) => {
        res.render("test.ejs", {
          parsed: parsed.text,
        });
      });
      console.log(message.bodyStructure.parameters);
      console.log("Message UID: " + message.uid);
      console.log("Date: " + parsed.date);
      console.log("From Email: " + parsed.from.value[0].address);
      console.log("Subject: " + parsed.subject);
      // console.log(strin.toString().split("").reverse().join(""));
      console.log("To: " + parsed.to.value[0].address);
      console.log("Message as Text: " + parsed.text);
      console.log("Message as HTML: " + parsed.html);
    }
    // Adds \\Seen flag to unseen messages
    await client.messageFlagsAdd({ seen: false }, ["\\Seen"]);
  } finally {
    // Make sure lock is released, otherwise next `getMailboxLock()` never returns
    lock.release();
  }
  await client.logout();
};
main().catch((err) => console.error(err));

What could be the solution, I looked at cron but it's not a good solution.
imapflow keep getting an error after first run
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
now the owner of this module said that you need to use another connection which an answer he gave to someone on an issue he raised.
But not sure how to go about this and imapflow doesn't have big audience to find answers.
Any help would be appreciated.

Do not call the client.connect inside the main, which could be causing this issue.
Try something like this:
client.connect().then(async () => {
  // better add rest of the code in a method and call that here
  await fetchNewMails();
});

And there is one event listener which will keep checking for new mail
  client.on('exists',async () => {
    await fetchNewMails();
  });

Hope this helps.

Thank you andridomace, I'm trying your suggestion, no luck so far.
Thanks for replying.
